# Error al tratar de cargar google maps en un fragment? Android Studio:

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment, fragment

Buenos días, estoy realizando el ejercicio de colocar un mapa a mi app, ya realicé un ejercicio que me funcionó correctamente usando una actividad, pero ahora estoy realizándolo con `Fragment` en un navigation drawer y me muestra error en la línea:

Se muestra: Inconvertible types; cannont cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment'

```
MapFragment fragment =(MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

A continuación el código:

```
public class MapActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
            .title("Uniagustiniana"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bogota, 16.1f));

    }
}
```

El archivo *`map_layout.xml`*:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.MapActivity">

<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como es un conjunto de fragments que son reemplazados por medio de las transacciones en el MainActivity, cuando cambio de //import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; a  //import android.app.Fragment; me aparece error en el MainActivity esto porque en todos los fragments importo support.v4, el siguiente es el MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Portal.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Biblioteca.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Evu.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                Directorio.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Siga.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Moodle.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Facebook.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                Twitter.OnFragmentInteractionLiastener, LinkedIn.OnFragmentInteractionListener, GooglePlus.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Flickr.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                Tour.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Instagram.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Youtube.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Noticias.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                Home.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Whatsapp.OnFragmentInteractionListener, MapActivity.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
//Bottom
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);//Los iconos del menu lateral toman su color original

    //BOTTON NAVIGATION VIEW

    final Fragment home = new Home();
    final Fragment noticias = new Noticias();
    final Fragment calendario = new Calendario();
    final Fragment ubicacion = new MapActivity();
    final Fragment pqrs = new PQRS();
    final Fragment preinscrip = new PreInscripcion();

    //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, home).commit();

    //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();


    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();
    }

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);//Los iconos del menu Bottom toman su color original
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.noticias) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, noticias).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.rutas) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, ubicacion).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cal_aca) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, calendario).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.pqrs) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, pqrs).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.preinscripcion) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, preinscrip).commit();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Alfredo coloca el puntero arriba del código que tiene color rojo y agrega a tu pregunta que mensaje se muestra. @Alfredo

Comment: Se muestra: Inconvertible types; cannont cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment'

Comment: No había visto esto, creo que debe tener algo que ver en la manera como están importadas las librerías, que me recomiendas?

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, he cambiado el import //import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; por  import android.app.Fragment; y desaparece el error, pero como es un navigation drawer al hacer este cambio me sale error en el MainActivity en las transacciones.

Comment: @Jorgesys  En el Main activity:  import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;  final Fragment home = new Home();
        final Fragment noticias = new Noticias();
        final Fragment calendario = new Calendario();
        final Fragment ubicacion = new MapActivity();

Comment: if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();
        }

Comment: @Jorgesys hay alguna manera de solucionar este error sin que afecte los demás fragments y las transacciones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `getChildFragmentManager()` fue introducido a partir de la API 17.
Si tu mínimo API es 17 (`minSdkVersion 17`) entonces no debe de haber ningún problema. Se deben importar las librerías de `Fragment` NO las de `Support Fragment` en todos los fragments. Prueba este código en `onViewCreated` de tu fragment MapActivity :

```
import android.app.Fragment;  //este en todos los Fragments que tengas
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    ...  onViewCreated ...
MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

En el xml:

```
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

En el `Main Activity` debes de importar también la librería de `Fragment`:

```
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Y las transacciones de los Fragments quedarían así:

```
MapActivity fragment = new MapActivity();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "mapactivity");
ft.commit();
```

Si tu `minSdkVersion` es -16 entonces debes de usar las librerías de `Support Fragment`.
Map Activity debe de ser forzosamente de tipo `Support Fragment`, los demás fragments no necesariamente:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import.com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; 
....
 SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment)
 getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

En el xml:

```
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

En el Main Activity importar la librería de `Support Fragment`:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Y las transacciones de los Fragments quedarían así:

```
MapActivity fragment = new MapActivity(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); ft.replace(R.id.frame,
fragment, "mapactivity"); ft.commit();
```

En caso de tener otros fragments que en su código java tengan importada la librería de Fragment (NO la de Support Fragment), en las transacciones cambiar a esta línea:

```
 android.app.FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

El map_layout.xml debería ser así:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.MapActivity"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, muy interesante tu ayuda, ya me ha ayudado mucho estoy haciendo los cambios y te cuento como me fue, te agradezco mucho.

Comment: Todo va muy bien, he seguido todo al pie de la letra y ya no muestra ningún error visual en el código, todas importan android.app.Fragment y he cambiado el nivel a 17 pero acciono el boton para ir al mapa la aplicacion se cierra, "se ha detenido".  at com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.MapActivity.onViewCreated(MapActivity.java:34)                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899).

Comment: El error está aquí yo cre:.  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
    }

Comment: Checa bien el código. En la última línea tienes `fragment.getChildFragmentManager();` en lugar de `fragment.getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: Ya lo he corregido, eso lo había hecho buscando salir del error pero así tambien se cae la app.  MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this); cuando quito estas dos líneas no se cae pero muestra el mapa sin marcador y no limíta la vista del mapa, lo muestra general.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                       at com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.MapActivity.onViewCreated(MapActivity.java:37)

Comment: Quizás el problema este en el xml. Edité la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

en tu xml no uses esta etiqueta para mostrar el mapa:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>
```

Te recomiendo que uses algo así:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Y a tu fragment le asignas con el findById a una variable de tipo MapView.

También puedes en el xml poner la etiqueta ..MapView dentro de un FrameLayout por orden además de no hacerlo en el xml de la actividad. Tienes que hacer en el xml un FrameLayout así y ya:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
  tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.MapActivity">
```

Luego en tu MainActivity inflas el fragmento con el findById(contentFrame) que sería el fragmento y ya en el xml del fragmento haces un FrameLayout con lo que puse al principio y recuerda 2 cosas importantes:

1) Usa este método para que inicie el mapa getMapAsync(this) y para que el "this" funcione el gragmento debe implementar esta interfaz OnMapReadyCallback.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Pero esto de que forma soluciona lo que pregunta el OP?

Comment: No le puede decir al fragmento que es un mapa, no esta inflando el mapa, entre otros consejos que le di que posiblemente estructuren mejor su código y corrijan el error