# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

Alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar este error de ejecución por favor, Estoy tratando de mostrar un mapa, en un fragmento, estoy trabajando desde la plantilla de un navigationDrawer.
He generado un fragment que contiene el siguiente código:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        LatLng bogota = new LatLng(4.653421, -74.145150);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bogota)
                .title("Uniagustiniana"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bogota, 16.1f));
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
```

El siguiente es el código map_layout.xml

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemasandroid.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustinianaapp.MapActivity">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>

/FrameLayout
```

Los errores en el Android Monitor salen así cuando intento ejecutar este fragment únicamente. El error se refiere a esta linea: fragment.getMapAsync(this);

[image: El error se refiere a esta linea: fragment.getMapAsync(this);]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir un poco más de información, los xml de las vistas sería una buena opción y señalarnos la línea 34 del activity

Comment: @Dwan Z, si está aquí:  MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this); la línea es:  fragment.getMapAsync(this);

Comment: que es this? si es de un fragmento, this no debería ser getActivity() ?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97104/error-al-tratar-de-cargar-google-maps-en-un-fragment-android-studio/97122#97122

Comment: @Dwan Z ya realice los cambios de esa pregunta pero no logré avanzar, allá tenía otros errores que corregí cambiando el nivel de api a 17 y usando el import.app.fragment, voy a volver mi xml a esa versión y miro que pasa.

Comment: Ya seguí nuevamente las indicaciones tal cual como indicas que haga en el xml, pero el java hago lo siguiente: me genera el mismo error:  MapView mMapView;   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = (MapView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

Comment: Y estas seguro que estas inicializando el servicio de maps?

Comment: Nosé donde está el problema, tengo otra app que inicia el mapa correctamente pero no lo hace en un fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente noto que tu clase `MapActivity` en realidad no es una `Activity`, si no un `Fragment`, el nombre tal vez no es adecuado.

---

Me parece que el problema es que estas interpretando mal como cargar un mapa, si cargas en `onViewCreated(),` en realidad se supone que usarías un `MapView` y no un `MapFragment`, como ejemplo revisa esta respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806967/250260

---

Si usas un `MapFragment`, usa el método `onCreateView()` para inicializar el `MapFragment` (no uses `onViewCreated()`) :

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);    
         MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

       return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, las respuestas están bien pues a otros le han funcionado voy a crear el proyecto nuevamente y lo revisaré.

Comment: Excelente Alfredo, saludos!

Comment: en `onCreateView()` puedes inicializar el Fragment(map_layout) y el ChildFragment, en ese orden así como lo tienes, o bien inicializas solo el Fragment y en `onViewCreated()` inicializas el ChildFragment